# Возможно ли: "свои куртизанки"?

Tags: выбор-слов

> ...сюда в Ренессанс начали съезжаться богатые флорентийские купцы. Они
>   любили тут строить дома своим куртизанкам (так что застройка по
>   большей части изысканная).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действительно, «куртизанка — это не содержанка и уж тем более не любовница». И не проститутка. Поскольку всё это не синонимы, напрашивается формула «свои любовницы из местных куртизанок».

С небольшой поправкой (*любили строить* — из детской лексики, а термин *застройка* намекает на квартальные, не меньше, масштабы строительства) последнюю фразу вижу такой: ***Они предпочитали тут строить дома своим любовницам из местных куртизанок (так что виды на город здесь по большей части изысканные)***.

Comment: Автор сказала: shampar лучше всех меня понял.

Comment: Пожелаем успехов всей команде. Спасибо тренеру и семье!

Answer (score 2):

С моей точки зрения, фраза построена правильно.

Тем не менее, я бы порекомендовал внести в неё пару усовершенствований.

Во-первых "в Ренессанс" звучит несколько необычно (хотя с формальной точки зрения правильно). Я бы скорее сказал "В эпоху Ренессанса".  Или "Во времена Ренессанса"

Во-вторых, фраза, помещённая в скобки, будет просодически звучать чуть лучше со словом "здесь":
"так что застройка здесь по большей части изысканная".

Чуть старомоднее будет добавить глагол "получилась" или "сложилась":
"так что застройка здесь по большей части получилась изысканная".

Но это уже вопрос стиля, почти что звукописи.

Answer (score 1):

...сюда в Ренессанс начали съезжаться богатые флорентийские купцы. Они любили **здесь** строить дома своим куртизанкам (так что застройка по большей части изысканная).

1) Может быть, лучше по стилю сочетаются наречия **сюда — здесь.**

Вариант: **Здесь же** *они любили строить дома своим куртизанкам...*

ТУТ, нареч. **Разг.** 1. В этом месте, здесь.

ЗДЕСЬ, местоим. нареч. 1. В этом месте.

2) ***Своим куртизанкам*** — это почти *своим любовницам*.
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Куртизанка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0)

**Куртиза́нка** (фр. courtisane, итал. cortigiana, первоначально - «придворная») — женщина лёгкого поведения, вращающаяся в высшем свете, ведущая светскую жизнь и **находящаяся на содержании богатых и влиятельных любовников.**

**Примечание** (по поводу предлагаемой правки)

Привычность и академичность для этого текста, **как мне кажется,** нежелательны. **Легкость и непринужденность** будут цениться читателями намного выше.

Answer (score 1):

Да, пожалуй, так сказать нельзя. Как нельзя сказать "свои проститутки". Но можно сказать "свои содержанки".

Comment: Низззя. Это разныые вещи. *Также следует отличать куртизанок от содержанок и королевских фавориток* (Вики)

Comment: Нда? А по цитате @Sharon примерно одно и то же. И там тоже Вики.

Comment: Я так не считаю. См. мой ответ.

Comment: Ну ладно, а с проститутками-то много общего? Но "свои проститутки" сказать уж точно нельзя, вот поэтому и "свои куртизанки" выглядят плоховато.

Answer (score 0):

Я не вижу принципиальных запретов. Да, немножко царапает слух двусмысленность, но заменить-то нечем.
Куртизанка - это не содержанка и уж тем более не любовница.

Есть, правда, большое сомнение, что автор правильно понимает смысл слова "куртизанка", а не вбухал его для "красивости", но если это сделано осознано, то придется согласиться.

Написал было, что, судя по всему, имеется в виду явление, называемое иначе "дама полусвета". Но потом понял, что ошибся, речь о другом периоде, Ренесансе. Так что синонима вообще нет убедительного.

Comment: А почему так сильно сомневаетесь в авторе? Она, вероятно, увидит Ваш ответ, поэтому, думаю, было бы корректно обосновать сомнения, если они не беспочвенны. По той же причине я бы слово "вбухал" поставил в кавычки. Или Вы знакомы с автором?

Comment: @grizzly Нет, конечно же с автором я не знаком (для меня странно даже то что вы сочли его женщиной), но слово "куртизанка" тут странно смотрится прежде всего из-за несоответствия самого явления описываемой ситуации. Я крепко сомневаюсь, что купцы (в Ренессанс!)  строили дома именно куртизанкам, то есть женщинам формально свободным, с творческой профессией...